# Proper es6 way of sharing global with sub-modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a complex server-side node module in folder form:

```
store
  |-index.js
  |-accounts
      |-index.js
      |-consumer.js
      |-provider.js
  |-site
      |-index.js
      |-portal.js
  |-etc.
```

Where, in `site/index.js` I am initialising a database context that should be accessible to all sub-modules (`accounts`, `site`, etc.) and `export`ing all of the sub-module interfaces, like:

```
import dbdriver from 'mydbdriver'
import settings from './settings'

const db = dbdriver.connect(settings)

export * from '../accounts' // depends on db
export * from '../site'     // depends on db
```

I have considered polluting the sub-module APIs via arguments (i.e. requiring the context to be passed into all relevant calls), but this is ugly, IMO.

Another idea is to have an initialiser for each module that would accept the context and cash in a module-scoped global, which would be required for every single file (again, yuck.)

Is there a cleaner, elegant es6 way of approaching this?

Comment: Passing state between functions that operate on that state is way cleaner than having singletons.

Comment: Related: https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Comment: @Ryan Only when the contract is unclear. In this case, literally *all* the sub-module functions utilise the state (db), so singleton is a better approach, but this is highly stylistically subjective. ;^)

Comment: That is way overkill for what I want to do. I think @riyaj-khan's approach is in the right direction.

Comment: @Dallas: This case isn’t an exception and it’ll probably bite at some point. Maybe when trying to write tests; maybe when trying to import modules without having any side-effects for other reasons.

Comment: @Ryan Not sure this is the correct place to debate about singleton access verses shared state via function contracts. For other cases, I would agree with you, or rather use classes for encapsulation, but this is not what I am looking for, here. Thanks for the input, anyway. :^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

define `db/index.js`

```
import dbdriver from 'mydbdriver'
import settings from './settings'

const db = dbdriver.connect(settings)
export db;
```

and in the `site/index.js`

```
import db from  db/index
export * from '../accounts' // depends on db
export * from '../site'     // depends on db


//use db here
```

In this way,whenever you want to use `db`,need to import the `db/index`

Comment: This may be what I have to do, though slightly different:

Place db singleton in `store/db.js`, then simply have all the sub-modules import this.